# Overriding a component variable with a fixture in a jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to figure out how to use jest to test a component and override a variable (but that isn't a prop) inside that component with a fixture.

I've simplified the actual code for this example, but the user variable cannot be used as a component prop.

**The component**

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const user: UserState = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your Country</h1>
      <p>{user.country}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**The test that I want to be able to write**

```
test("component renders correct country for user", async () => {
  const userFromBrazilFixture = userFixture[0]
  const { findByText } = render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Route>
        <MyComponent />
      </Route>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )

  // Ensure we render correct country
  const userCountry = await findByText("Brazil")
  expect(userCountry.textContent).toEqual("Brazil")
})
```

If I have a fixture for this user, how can I pass that into the test in a way so it overrides the `const user: UserState....` variable inside the actual component?

Comment: `useSelector` is a Redux hook, right? So you should probably mount your component in a store context that has the global state you want. You may be tempted to mock `useSelector` instead - resist that temptation, don't mock what you don't own.

Comment: OK thanks for the tip, that makes sense. I'll look into that